# How to get the proper URL from this tag value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, formatting, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsstringencoding

How to get the proper url link from the tag value. I have used NSXMLParser for parsing and parsed content successfully but stucked with the url value like:

```
<value> http://example.site.com/%3Ca%20href%3D%22/taxonomy/term/3%22%3ETheater%3C/a%3E </value>
```

I have tried with some string replacement operation but not any good result.

How i format that string value and get the exact url string.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Ultimately if you want to hit it you again have to convert it.

Comment: i have to show it also and the unwanted character shouldn't be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *value = @"http://example.site.com/%3Ca%20href%3D%22/taxonomy/term/3%22%3ETheater%3C/a%3E";


NSString *formattedValue = [value stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *array = [formattedValue componentsSeparatedByString:@"<a"];
NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Comment: thanks Inder for your reply. i am having this value after using your code
"http://example.site.com/<a href="/taxonomy/term/3">Theater</a>"

 but i want to ignore those tags too



accepting answer :)